# Pandas filter grouped data and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group data in a `DataFrame`, filter out outliers in each group (e.g. quantile(0.95)) and then aggregate the results for each group.

I tried to do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dff = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(8), "B": list("aabbbbcc")})
group = dff.groupby(["B"])
print(group.mean())
group1 = group.apply(lambda g: g[g["A"] < g["A"].quantile(0.95)])

print("-------")
print(group1.mean())
```

However, it does not seem to do the right thing, as the `group1` object is actually not a `DataFrameGroupBy` as is the `group` object. I could not find any function which returns an filtered `DataFrameGroupBy` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by grouping again on "B". Note that to do this the index will need to be reset (with `drop = True` to avoid duplicating "B" in the dataframe), or the `groupby` function will produce an error stating that "B" is both an index level and a column label. Try replacing `group1.mean()` with:

```
group1.reset_index(drop=True).groupby("B").mean()
```